# Move game object in direction its facing without rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I want an object (bullet) in 2d space move towards the direction its rotated in. Im using

```
   transform.position += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
```

which makes it just move upwards no matter what rotation the z axis has. What am i missing?

The bullet has no ned for a rigidbody2d component so i want to do it without.

Comment: You are using Vector3.up which is equal to Vector3(0, 1, 0)  which means : Y ...

Comment: I am aware of that. Im not sure what to do though.

Comment: I would find out the current direction its rotated in, stick to that direction and move...not sure

Answer (score 0):

Multiply transform by any desired numbers

```
transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
```

[**ref**](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/616195/how-to-make-an-object-go-the-direction-it-is-facin.html)

Comment: This is exactly what i did. Only that .forward doesnt work when i use an x,y 2d space. It should be Vector3.up. But the solution is to use transform.up instead.

Comment: it depends that where is your gameobject's forward